# Bootstrap : align button text left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I align text to the left within a bootstrap button? I have multiple buttons with text of varying length, and all the button need to have same width. I have achieved this using the class `col-xs-11`.

Sample button code below:

```
<input type="button" value="Applicant/Subsidiary" id="mybutton" name="test" class="primary-btn col-xs-11">
```

Is it possible to achieve this without creating a custom style, other than what is provided by bootstrap?
I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

just add `text-left` class

```
<input type="button" value="Applicant/Subsidiary" id="mybutton" name="test" class="primary-btn col-xs-11 text-left">
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? this works in Bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: Have you checked that your custom CSS doesn't override it?

Comment: I have tried my code through Chrome DevTools in http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.1/docs/css/ and it works

Comment: With Bootstrap 5.X you need to use **text-start** to align it left, or for right **text-end**

Answer (score 30):

The issue is not how to css text-align to the left, the original post was asking if there is a bootstrap class name(s) works for it.

The .text-left works, but the trouble is there is a .btn that is stronger than text-left, I think this is something bootstrap need to think about.

Checkout this screenshot that I did a test with Chrome inspect on Bootstrap's site.
[image]

In my Chrome, I add "text-left" on the demo button, and this is the result.
Therefore, have !important on it!

```
.text-left {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Exactly the problem I am seeing. +1 for the screenshot :-)

Comment: !important applies to one specific declaration in a CSS rule. It doesn't apply to a class.

Answer (score 17):

Or use inline styling for if its just one single button

```
style="text-align:left; padding-left:6px"
```

Comment: I'm seeing this problem with flask and Flask_Bootstrap-3.3.5.6. This answer fixed it for me so +1 thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can just apply css the normal way instead of using additional classes.

```
/*specific button*/    
#mybutton {
   text-align: left;
}

/*all input that have type button*/
input[type='button'] {
   text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question recently while searching for how to align button text left in Bootstrap 5 **while using flex**, the solution using `text-left` does not work in this case, and since `flex` is ubiquitous in Bootstrap 5 I though sharing the following example might help somebody:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-start flex-grow-1">wide text</div>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-info">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give button class "text-start":

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block alert-primary col-12 text-start">
   <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
   Lorem ipsum
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add !important to your button definition and it will force utilization.

Comment: !important applies to one specific declaration in a CSS rule. It doesn't apply to a class.