# Bootstrap: left align text in btn-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using some column-width Bootstrap buttons defined using the btn-block class. However, the text inside them is centered by default, and I'd like to left-justify it so it looks more natural in my form. Is there a good Bootstrap solution to this, or do I have to use CSS?

What I've got:

```
<a href="url" class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Push Meh</a>
```

Comment: Similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675063/bootstrap-align-button-text-left

Comment: Oh, weird. I wonder why that didn't come up when I searched for it.

Comment: Also, the bootstrap solution there doesn't seem to work (at least in bootstrap 3.3.5) and the other one messes with the CSS which I'd like to avoid in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is perhaps a bit of a hacky way to do it, but achieves your desired effect:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button"><span class="pull-left">Push Meh</span>&nbsp;</a>
```

And a [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Si2ekU0QI6)

Comment: same without `&nbsp;` sorcery: `<button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit"><span class="pull-left">Push Meh</span></button>`

Comment: @DejaVu I used the `&nbsp;` as the one is his example is an `<a>` tag, which doesn't have the same spacing as a `<button>`. Try my example without it, it's kinda awful. And glad you got this working. Cheers! Seen here: http://www.bootply.com/Xesh61eXF3

Comment: @TimLewis according to [**docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags), you can `Use the button classes on an <a>, <button>, or <input> element.` Your solution works, no salt from my side, just a comment.

Comment: @DejaVu Haha yes I know, and I wasn't offended or anything, just explaining why the `<a>` class needed the *wizardry* :P

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using Bootstrap 4.1, there is a `text-left` class that can be used with `btn-block`:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-left">Push Meh</a>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3.7 has a 'text-left' class too, but it doesn't work in this case because it doesn't have the `!important` rule (while it does in Bootstrap 4.1) and is declared before the 'btn' class which has a `text-align: center` rule.

Comment: @GiorgioTempesta That's true. Would you like to upvote this answer? The question doesn't specify any particular version, and for the latest bootstrap I think it is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: You’re right, this is far better than the accepted answer, I was just pointing out that Bootstrap 3 has it too, even if it’s useless in this case. Upvote deserved!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is through flexbox. You may use the justify-content property and don't forget the display:flex as well. Otherwise, it will not work. (see code below)

```
a.btn {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start; }
```

You can learn more about it here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Cheers!

Comment: If you can use CSS then a simple `text-align: left;` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily use text-left first before your btn like this:

```
<a href="url" class="text-left btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Push Meh</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do it is by text-left class for Bootstrap 4

```
 <a href="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block text-left">
      <span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-edit-alt" data-inline="true"></span> Start a discussion  
    </a>
```